# How can I change the default highlighted color of focused ListField row?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can anybody help me on this?

I tried to override `onFocus()`, `onUnfocus()` and `paint()` methods of ListField.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do a simple web search before post to stackoverflow.

Please go through the following links.

[Create a Custom Listfield - Change Highlight Color when Scrolling](http://berrytutorials.blogspot.com/2009/11/create-custom-listfield-change.html) by John Banks

[Blackberry Tip: Change the default focus highlight color of ListField](http://intridea.com/2011/2/25/blackberry-tip-change-the-default-focus-highlight-color-of-listfield?blog=company) by Yincan Sheng

Comment: I already checked these two articles and tried them. However i checked them again, 2nd article works now... I think i missed something at first. Thank you.